# Validate inAppPurchase Subscription account when login to app which other credentials

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I implemented auto-renewable inApp purchase in my App. Users needs to buy the subscription to complete the signup process. Everything is good but there is one issue I am facing.

I applied a check to validate subscription expiry on first initial screen when user log in. But the issue is... when I purchase a subscription on signup and then login to the app with other account it still picks up old subscription details which I used to buy the subscription in previous app account.

Issue :-

When I am make an account with apple id after completing buy subscription process and then log out from that app account and login with another app account it log in the user without any purchase error. It is picking up the old purchase receipt and details even in new app account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has no idea about any of your app user accounts, only the underlying Apple Id that made the purchase. What you should do is store the subscription status for the user on your server and retrieve it when the user logs in. You can implement server-side logic to prevent more than one of your user Ids from sharing the same Apple receipt.

Setting up a server to manage subscriptions is a non-trivial task that's probably better explained in a blog-post elsewhere. Here are a few posts that may help get you started:

1. [iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/05/22/ios-subscriptions-are-hard)
2. [How to Build a Great iOS In-app Purchase Subscription Server](https://www.revenuecat.com/2019/07/16/altconf-subscriptions-are-hard)